# Array not assigning IDs from database correctly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I currently have a select statement building an array and being looped for values. It's returning the right values but it's not assigning the correct assignment.

So I'm treating locations as array keys, which is working right, but for example in the array below, `Office 1` should have an array that has `ID 1` assigned `Room Main` and `ID 2` assigned to `Room Extra`, but instead the `display_id` is in an array outside of the display names.

My query:

```
SELECT l.id , location_name, d.id as display_id, display_name, location_id
    FROM locations l
    inner join displays d
    ON d.location_id = l.id;";
```

My code:

```
$displayResult = $mysqlConn->query($getDisplays);

    $displayNames = array();
    foreach($displayResult as $subArray) {
      if(!array_key_exists($subArray['location_name'], $displayNames)) {
        $displayNames[$subArray['location_name']] = array();

      }
        $displayNames[] = $subArray['display_id'];
        $displayNames[$subArray['location_name']][] = $subArray['display_name'];

    }
```

This currently dumps this array:

```
Array
(
[Office 1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Room Main
        [1] => Room Extra
    )

[0] => 1
[1] => 2
[Office 2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Room Conference
        [1] => Room Break
    )

[2] => 3
[3] => 4
```

I just need display_id assigned to display_name because I'm building links for each display_name and I"m trying to save the display_id as the URL value for each one.

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share an example of the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your correct loop should be:

```
foreach($displayResult as $subArray) {
    if(!array_key_exists($subArray['location_name'], $displayNames)) {
        $displayNames[$subArray['location_name']] = array();

    }
    // here you add `display_name` under key `display_id`
    $displayNames[$subArray['location_name']][$subArray['display_id']] = $subArray['display_name'];
}
```

Comment: Yes that's perfect! Thanks so much, I was thinking I should be setting it outside of the subarray but that would have ended up creating an additional array.